# Adding external library to WCF service causes exception

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have an external library with some code in it. I also have a WCF service library that I want to add my external library to. I choose the "Add Reference" command to add the external library to my service library. Now when I "start" my service library (using the VS service host) I get this exception:

[image]

I really need this external library, so what to do to prevent this exception?

Comment: It's not adding the library that is causing the exception, it may be the code IN the library.  So what does the code/library do?  Does the library depend on another library that you haven't added (the exception hints at that)?

Comment: Also, look at the complete exception (the part that's scrolled off the screen). It may tell you _why_ there was a type load exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options here:

- The assembly you´re referencing is explicitly build for x68 or x64
  and your servicehost is running the opposite or
- The assembly you´re referencing requires a third assembly not
  present on your system, use fusion log to check for binding errors

Comment: I am running a x64, and compiled to x86. Usually my programm simply runs in x86 mode, but WCF seems to not support this.

Comment: I dont think WCF is the issue here. Did you actually solve your Problem? What are you running x64, your OS or the WCFServiceHost?